# Sending multiple email with different body in Php Mailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

How am i able to send multiple email with different body?

I have this loop for sending email:

**UPDATED:**

```
                // $arr[] here contains email from database
                // $arrcount = length of $arr[]

                for ($x = 0; $x < $arrcount; $x++)
                {
                    $email = $arr[$x]; 

                $body = "
                    <div>   
                    <h3>Good Day!</h3>

                            You can now <b> <a href = 'project/welcome/signin.php?email=$email'> sign-in and accept this invitation </a> </b>
                        <br>
                     </div>
                "; 
                    $mail->addAddress($email, "You");
                    $query2 = "Insert into ws_invites(user_id,email,date_invited) values ('$myid','$email',now())";
                    $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
                }
                $mail->addReplyTo('myserver@gmail.com', 'Name');
                $mail->WordWrap = 50;
                $mail->Subject = 'You have been invited';
                $mail->Body    = $body;
                $mail->isHTML(true);
                if(!$mail->send()) { 
                   $fault = "true";
                }
```

Let's assume I have  3 different emails - **email1@gmail.com**, **email2@gmail.com**, **email3@gmail.com**.

Now what happens here is that the value of the `$email` of this link: `<a href = 'project/welcome/signin.php?email=$email'>` is equivalent to `email3@gmail.com` which is the last recipient of the message and both `email1@gmail.com` and `email2@gmail.com` receives that email too which is `email3@gmail.com`.

So i concluded that the program finishes the loops first before sending email. Now what I want is that each loop sends their corresponding email and not that of the email of the last recipient only. Could this be possible? How?

Comment: You say you use this for sending email but I don't see anywhere in the code where the process is to send email. All I see is a new entry into the database. What is the value of `$arrcount`? How many times do you want to insert this information into the database? Your insert statement is inside a loop.

Comment: Look at the mailing list example provided in the examples folder with phpmailer, and make sure you are using latest version.

Comment: Updated the question. Hope you can help me.

Comment: @Makudex , I have the same problem , please what was the solution , I'm really stuck at this point.

Answer (score 2):

You can add mail sending in your for loop.  This sends in order. But this can be slow. Try this change:

```
$mail->addReplyTo('myserver@gmail.com', 'Name');
$mail->WordWrap = 50;
$mail->Subject = 'You have been invited';
$mail->isHTML(true);

for ($x = 0; $x < $arrcount; $x++)
{
    $email = $arr[$x];

    $body = "
    <div>
        <h3>Good Day!</h3>
        You can now <b> <a href = 'project/welcome/signin.php?email=$email'> sign-in and accept this invitation </a> </b>
        <br>
    </div>
    ";
    $mail->addAddress($email, "You");
    $query2 = "Insert into ws_invites(user_id,email,date_invited) values ('$myid','$email',now())";
    $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
    $mail->Body = $body;
    if(!$mail->send()) {
       $fault = "true";
    }
}
```